# cannot import name kivy_config_fn

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, python-3.4, importerror

I installed the Kivy lib, and have been trying to get it to work all day. 
I tried following the simple tutorial:

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.9.0')

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label


    class MyApp(App):

        def build(self):
            return Label(text='Hello world')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

When trying to run from file i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from kivy.logger import Logger, LOG_LEVELS
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 61, in <module>
    from random import randint
  File "random.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 315, in <module>
    from kivy.config import ConfigParser
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\config.py", line 272, in <module>
    from kivy import kivy_config_fn
ImportError: cannot import name 'kivy_config_fn'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Confusingly enough, it works in the interactive just fine... *(able to build class and run app with exact same code)*

**Notes:**

- Already tried reinstalling
- Installed Kivy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

**Specs:**

- Window 8.1
- Python 3.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some googling, i finally found my answer. 
I followed this guide and got everything to work:
[How to use PTVS to develop and run Kivy applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20131115020945/http://www.ocularsoftware.com/2013/11/how-to-use-python-tools-for-visual-studio-to-develop-and-run-kivy-applications/)

And also this **from 2013** stating that you can't use Kivy as a regular module.
[How to use PyDev to develop and run Kivy applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20131216025529/http://www.ocularsoftware.com/2012/11/how-to-use-pydev-to-develop-and-run-kivy-applications-on-windows)